# Soap webservices PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am Trying to use SOAP web services but i am new in services so facing some problem hope u will help me.

What i Try :

[My Example](http://pastebin.com/vfR7YJjA)

Getting Response :

stdClass Object ( [GetAllMessageListResult] => stdClass Object ( [any] => ) )

Please Help Me how i can start to work With SOAP web services with authentication in header.

Thanks & Regards
Rohit Gilbile

Comment: What exactly is your issue, we need more information than what you've supplied...

Comment: Darren i need some hint to work with soap web service cuz i am working first time on it. and in my example first it authenticate in header with username and password after that call a function xyz with one parameter...if u give me some link or demo it will be more helpful to me its small request.thanks